# Bash script getting syntax error in CD/CI pipeline

Tags: bash

I have two folders in my app: frontend/admin and backend/picking. From my script, I extract absolute path variables (frontend and backend). 
And then organize them into arrays. Then I run one 'package.json' script after looping across the directory. This script performs as expected when executed locally. However, I'm receiving the following error in my CD/CI pipeline:

```
'./script/generate-graphql.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected "("'.
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
#!/bin/sh

root_path="$( cd  "$(dirname "$0")/../../.." >/dev/null 2>&1 || exit ; pwd -P )"
admin_panel_path="$root_path/frontend/admin-panel"
picking_path="$root_path/backend/picking"

paths=($admin_panel_path $picking_path)

for path in "${paths[@]}"; do
  cd $path
  npm run single-generate-graphql-types
done

echo "Successfully generated graphql types"
```

Comment: You are using a shell that doesn't support arrays. Changing the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` may work, assuming your CI framework honors the shebang.

Comment: How come it works locally.

Comment: @Krisna On some systems `sh` points to `bash`. On others it doesn’t.

Comment: How are you running it locally? `bash ./script/generate-graphql.sh` is very different from `./script/generate-graphql.sh` or `sh ./script/generate-graphql.sh`.

Comment: I am running via package.json. in package.json script is like this: `"generate-graphql-types": "./script/generate-graphql.sh",`

Comment: In terminal I run `npm run generate-graphql-types`

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I learn something today.